# Forbidden Attributes Error in Rails 4 when encountering a situation where one would have used attr_accessible in earlier versions of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel, attr-accessible, strong-parameters

With the recent upgrade to Rails 4, updating attributes using code resembling the below does not work, I get a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes` error:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```

Where User has the following attr_accessible line in the model:

```
attr_accessible :role_ids, :as =>admin
# or any attribute other than :role_ids contained within :user
```

How do you accomplish the same task in Rails 4?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Rails 4 now has features from the [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/) gem built in by default.

One no longer has to make calls `:as => :admin`, nor do you need the `attr_accessible :user_attribute, :as => admin` in your model.  The reason for this is that, by default, rails apps now have 'security' for every attribute on models.  You have to `permit` the attribute you want to access / modify.

All you need to do now is call `permit` during `update_attributes`:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user], permit[:user_attribute])
```

or, to be more precise:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user].permit(:role_ids))
```

This single line, however, allows any user to modify the `permit`ted role.  You have to remember to only allow access to this action by an administrator or any other desired role through another filter such as the following:

```
authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
```

. . .  which would work if you're using Devise and CanCan for authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 39):

If you create a new Rails 4 site you'll notice that generated controllers now include a private method which you use to receive your sanitised params. This is a nice idiom, and looks something like this:

```
private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end
```

The old way of allowing mass assignment was to use something like:

```
attr_accessible :username, :email, :password
```

on your model to mark certain parameters as accessible.

### Upgrading

To upgrade you have several options. Your best solution would be to refactor your controllers with a params method. This might be more work than you have time for right now though.

### Protected_attributes gem

The alternative would be to use the protected_attributes gem which reinstates the attr_accessible method. This makes for a slightly smoother upgrade path with one major caveat.

### Major Caveat

In Rails 3 any model without an attr_accessible call allowed all attributes though.

In Rails 4 with the protected_attributes gem this behaviour is reversed. Any model without an attr_accessible call has all attributes restricted. You must now declare attr_accessible on all your models. This means, if you haven't been using attr_accessible, you'll need to add this to all your models, which may be as much work as just creating a params method.

https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes

Answer (score 9):

This problem might also be caused by the [Cancan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Just add to application_controller.rb

```
before_filter do
  resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
  method = "#{resource}_params"
  params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```

Works without any further modifications of code
got it from here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835#issuecomment-18663815

Comment: Totally helpful, would wasted hours if not for this.

Comment: This fixed it for me, but I'm not using cancan? Only devise.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to add your new user_params method to the controller action:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    @user.save
    redirect_to 'wherever'
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  ....
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(blog_params)
    redirect_to home_path, notice:  "Your profile has been successfully updated."
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :others)
  end
```

Comment: @pixelearth, If you know why please let me know :)

Comment: please explain why he needs to do this

Comment: Where are your blog_params?