# When to use slice vs. permit in ActionController::Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assuming I have an `ActionController::Parameters` object like

`params = ActionController::Parameters.new(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)`

I can call `slice` on it or `permit` to get/allow only certain parameters.

At first sight, they return the same thing

```
> params.slice(:a)
=> {"a"=>1}

> params.permit(:a)
[18:21:45.302147] Unpermitted parameters: b, c
=> {"a"=>1}
```

But if I call `to_h` on it `params.slice(:a).to_h` returns an empty hash, while `params.permit(:a).to_h` returns an hash with key `:a`. As far as I understood, this is the case, because `:a` was not permitted.

What I wonder now is, what is the use case of `slice`, if I could just use `permit`?

Answer (score 8):

One difference I could think of is `permit` cuts nested hash if you don't explicitly specify the nested keys while `slice` allows nested hash:

```
# params = { a: 'a', nested: { nested_1: 1, nested_2: 2 } }
params.permit(:a, :nested) # => { a: 'a' }
params.slice(:a, :nested) # => { a: 'a', { nested_1: 1, nested_2: 2 } }
```

Another difference is in Rails 4, `permit` won't raise `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes` when calling in `.update_attributes(...)` [(answered here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17450346/1815779):

```
user.update_attributes(params.slice(:email)) # will raise ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes
user.update_attributes(params.permit(:email)) # wont raise error
```

Answer (score 1):

`slice` gives ability to slice a hash with selected keys.

where as `.permit` returns a new ActionController::Parameters instance that includes only the given filters and sets the permitted attribute for the object to true. This is useful for limiting which attributes should be allowed for mass updating.

I would say slice is for everything dealing with Hash and permit is created [using slice pattern](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/) but more in context of url params.

Hope it helps!

Also read this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/permit

Comment: `slice` also returns an instance of ActionController::Parameters again. And since that class was introduced for strong parameters, I wonder why the slice method which is an extension of Rails for the Hash class should be used. For pure hashes I agree that it makes sense to have it.